# Live streaming Channel Multiview used ffmpeg X11grab and shaka packager

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, vlc, live

I have been trying to live stream channel multiview used xvfb, firefox, vlc, ffmpeg and shaka packager.
1). Making virtual display used Xvfb.
2). Popping up a web page used fireforx on 1).
3). Drawing nine video(each channel) used vlc plugin on 2).
4). Capturing 2) used ffmpeg library, x11grab.
5). Transcoding 4) to  FHD(HEVC)+10 Audio(each channel sound + dummy), FHD(H.264)+no sound, HD(H.264)+no sound, SD(H.264)+no sound, nHD(H.264)+no sound
6). packaging 5) used Shaka Packager

This is my command. shell script

```
function exec-xvfb () {
$XVFB :$display_port -br -noreset -nolisten tcp -screen 0 1920x1080x24 &}

function exec-firefox () {
    AUDIO_CTRL_PATH="$audio_ctrl_port:/TEST/vlcenv/.sync.dat" VLC_INFO_PATH=/TEST/vlcenv/vlc_info.dat AUDIO_SHARE_KEY="$AUDIO_SHARE_KEY" AUDIO_SHARE_PATH=/TEST/vlcenv/.share.shm MOSAIC_META_PATH=/TEST/meta_bin.dat DISPLAY=":$display_port" $FIREFOX --display=:$display_port --no remote --profile /TEST/browser -width 1920 -height 1080 http://127.0.0.1:8021/template/best_channel_9_1/page/index.html &
}

function transcoder () {
    AUDIO_CTRL_PATH="$audio_ctrl_port:/TEST/vlcenv/.sync.dat" VLC_INFO_PATH=/TEST/vlcenv/vlc_info.dat 
AUDIO_SHARE_KEY="$AUDIO_SHARE_KEY" AUDIO_SHARE_PATH=/TEST/vlcenv/.share.shm 
MOSAIC_META_PATH=/TEST/meta_bin.dat DISPLAY=":$display_port" 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/transcoder/lib:/transcoder/lib/cuda /transcoder/gpu/transcoder -y -re \
    -analyzeduration 0 -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -pkt_size 128000 -i syc://@:$trc_sync_port?dummy=1 \
    -analyzeduration 0 -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -pkt_size 128000 -i syc://@:$(($trc_sync_port+1)) \
    -analyzeduration 0 -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -pkt_size 128000 -i syc://@:$(($trc_sync_port+2)) \
    -analyzeduration 0 -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -pkt_size 128000 -i syc://@:$(($trc_sync_port+3)) \
    -analyzeduration 0 -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -pkt_size 128000 -i syc://@:$(($trc_sync_port+4)) \
    -analyzeduration 0 -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -pkt_size 128000 -i syc://@:$(($trc_sync_port+5)) \
    -analyzeduration 0 -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -pkt_size 128000 -i syc://@:$(($trc_sync_port+6)) \
    -analyzeduration 0 -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -pkt_size 128000 -i syc://@:$(($trc_sync_port+7)) \
    -analyzeduration 0 -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -pkt_size 128000 -i syc://@:$(($trc_sync_port+8)) \
    -analyzeduration 0 -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -pkt_size 128000 -i syc://@:$(($trc_sync_port+9)) \
    -analyzeduration 0 -f x11grab -draw_mouse 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 29.97 -i :$display_port.0+0,0,nomouse \
    -c:a libfdk_aac -ar:a 48000 -ac:a 2 -b:a 128000 -vf hwupload_cuda=device=$gpu_no,scale_npp=1920:1080:format=yuv420p -gpu $gpu_no -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset:v fast -profile:v main -r 29.97 -g 15 -b:v 6000000 -bufsize 14000000 -maxrate 7000000 \
    -map 0:a -map 1:a -map 2:a -map 3:a -map 4:a -map 5:a -map 6:a -map 7:a -map 8:a -map 9:a -map 10:v -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:$trc_output_port?pkt_size=1316 \
    -an -vf hwupload_cuda=device=$gpu_no,scale_npp=1920:1080:format=yuv420p -gpu $gpu_no -c:v h264_nvenc -preset:v fast -profile:v main -r 29.97 -g 15 -b:v 4000000 -bufsize 8000000 -maxrate 4000000 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:$(($trc_output_port+1))?pkt_size=1316 \
    -an -vf hwupload_cuda=device=$gpu_no,scale_npp=1280:720:format=yuv420p -gpu $gpu_no -c:v h264_nvenc -preset:v fast -profile:v main -r 29.97 -g 15 -b:v 2000000 -bufsize 4000000 -maxrate 2000000 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:$(($trc_output_port+2))?pkt_size=1316 \
    -an -vf hwupload_cuda=device=$gpu_no,scale_npp=720:480:format=yuv420p -gpu $gpu_no -c:v h264_nvenc -preset:v fast -profile:v main -r 29.97 -g 15 -b:v 1500000 -bufsize 3000000 -maxrate 1500000 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:$(($trc_output_port+3))?pkt_size=1316 \
    -an -vf hwupload_cuda=device=$gpu_no,scale_npp=640:360:format=yuv420p -gpu $gpu_no -c:v h264_nvenc -preset:v fast -profile:v main -r 29.97 -g 15 -b:v 800000 -bufsize 1600000 -maxrate 800000 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:$(($trc_output_port+4))?pkt_size=1316 \main &
}

function packager () { 
    rm -rf $OUTPUT/*
    /packager/packager \ 

    "in=udp://127.0.0.1:$trc_output_port,stream=0,init_segment=$OUTPUT/audio/0/audio_4.mp4,segment_template=$OUTPUT/audio/0/\$Time\$.m4s" \                 "in=udp://127.0.0.1:$trc_output_port,stream=1,init_segment=$OUTPUT/audio/1/audio_4.mp4,segment_template=$OUTPUT/audio/1/\$Time\$.m4s" \
    "in=udp://127.0.0.1:$trc_output_port,stream=2,init_segment=$OUTPUT/audio/2/audio_4.mp4,segment_template=$OUTPUT/audio/2/\$Time\$.m4s" \
    "in=udp://127.0.0.1:$trc_output_port,stream=3,init_segment=$OUTPUT/audio/3/audio_4.mp4,segment_template=$OUTPUT/audio/3/\$Time\$.m4s" \
    "in=udp://127.0.0.1:$trc_output_port,stream=4,init_segment=$OUTPUT/audio/4/audio_4.mp4,segment_template=$OUTPUT/audio/4/\$Time\$.m4s" \
    "in=udp://127.0.0.1:$trc_output_port,stream=5,init_segment=$OUTPUT/audio/5/audio_4.mp4,segment_template=$OUTPUT/audio/5/\$Time\$.m4s" \
    "in=udp://127.0.0.1:$trc_output_port,stream=6,init_segment=$OUTPUT/audio/6/audio_4.mp4,segment_template=$OUTPUT/audio/6/\$Time\$.m4s" \
    "in=udp://127.0.0.1:$trc_output_port,stream=7,init_segment=$OUTPUT/audio/7/audio_4.mp4,segment_template=$OUTPUT/audio/7/\$Time\$.m4s" \
    "in=udp://127.0.0.1:$trc_output_port,stream=8,init_segment=$OUTPUT/audio/8/audio_4.mp4,segment_template=$OUTPUT/audio/8/\$Time\$.m4s" \
    "in=udp://127.0.0.1:$trc_output_port,stream=9,init_segment=$OUTPUT/audio/9/audio_4.mp4,segment_template=$OUTPUT/audio/9/\$Time\$.m4s" \
    "in=udp://127.0.0.1:$trc_output_port,stream=video,init_segment=$OUTPUT/video/0/video_4.mp4,segment_template=$OUTPUT/video/0/\$Time\$.m4s" \
    "in=udp://127.0.0.1:$(($trc_output_port+1)),stream=video,init_segment=$OUTPUT/video/1/video_4.mp4,segment_template=$OUTPUT/video/1/\$Time\$.m4s" \
    "in=udp://127.0.0.1:$(($trc_output_port+2)),stream=video,init_segment=$OUTPUT/video/2/video_4.mp4,segment_template=$OUTPUT/video/2/\$Time\$.m4s" \
    "in=udp://127.0.0.1:$(($trc_output_port+3)),stream=video,init_segment=$OUTPUT/video/3/video_4.mp4,segment_template=$OUTPUT/video/3/\$Time\$.m4s" \
    "in=udp://127.0.0.1:$(($trc_output_port+4)),stream=video,init_segment=$OUTPUT/video/4/video_4.mp4,segment_template=$OUTPUT/video/4/\$Time\$.m4s" \
    --segment_duration 10 --fragment_duration 10 --minimum_update_period 10 --allow_codec_switching --preserved_segments_outside_live_window 24 --time_shift_buffer_depth 40 \
    --mpd_output $OUTPUT/$output_mpd.mpd
}
```

vlc warning and error messages when duration 7

```
...
adaptive debug: Timeline
adaptive debug: Element #1 d=669670 r=0 @t=6321195
adaptive debug: Element #2 d=576576 r=0 @t=6990865
adaptive debug: Element #3 d=669670 r=0 @t=7567441
adaptive debug: Element #4 d=672673 r=0 @t=8237111
adaptive debug: Element #5 d=561561 r=0 @t=8909784
adaptive debug: Element #6 d=654655 r=0 @t=9471345
adaptive debug: Element #7 d=630631 r=0 @t=10126000
adaptive debug: Updated MPD, next update in 7s
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 223 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 157 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 91 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 24 ms)
adaptive debug: Retrieving http://192.168.0.181:81/300/audio/5/9451440.m4s @0
adaptive debug: Retrieving http://192.168.0.181:81/300/video/0/9475185.m4s @0
adaptive debug: Retrieving http://192.168.0.181:81/300/300.mpd @0
main debug: creating access: http://192.168.0.181:81/300/300.mpd
main debug: (path: \\192.168.0.181:81\300\300.mpd)
main debug: looking for access module matching "http": 26 candidates
http debug: resolving 192.168.0.181 ...
http debug: outgoing request: GET /300/300.mpd HTTP/1.1 Host:192.168.0.181:81 Accept: */* Accept-Language: en_US User-Agent: VLC/3.0.11 LibVLC/3.0.11 Range: bytes=0- 
http debug: incoming response: HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content Server: nginx Date: Mon, 17 Aug 2020 09:10:08 GMT Content-Type: application/octet-stream Content-Length: 10406 Last-Modified: Mon, 17 Aug 2020 09:10:08 GMT Connection: keep-alive ETag: "5f3a4970-28a6" Content-Range: bytes 0-10405/10406 
main debug: using access module "access"
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_block": 24 candidates
prefetch debug: using 10406 bytes buffer, 10406 bytes read
main debug: using stream_filter module "prefetch"
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 24 candidates
main debug: no stream_filter modules matched
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "inflate": 24 candidates
main debug: no stream_filter modules matched
prefetch debug: end of stream
main debug: removing module "prefetch"
main debug: removing module "access"
main debug: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
main debug: using xml reader module "xml"
adaptive debug: MPD profile=urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011 mediaPresentationDuration=0 minBufferTime=2
adaptive debug: BaseUrl=http://192.168.0.181:81/300/
adaptive debug: Period
adaptive debug: BaseAdaptationSet 0
adaptive debug: Representation 0 [mp4a]
adaptive debug: InitSegmentTemplate #0 url=http://192.168.0.181:81/300/audio/0/audio_4.mp4 duration 0
adaptive debug: SegmentTemplate #12 url=http://192.168.0.181:81/300/audio/0/$Time$.m4s duration 0
adaptive debug: Timeline
adaptive debug: Element #1 d=629760 r=1 @t=6930480
adaptive debug: Element #3 d=631680 r=0 @t=8190000
adaptive debug: Element #4 d=629760 r=3 @t=8821680
adaptive debug: Representation 1 [mp4a]
adaptive debug: InitSegmentTemplate #0 url=http://192.168.0.181:81/300/audio/1/audio_4.mp4 duration 0
adaptive debug: SegmentTemplate #12 url=http://192.168.0.181:81/300/audio/1/$Time$.m4s duration 0
...
adaptive debug: Timeline
adaptive debug: Element #1 d=576576 r=0 @t=6990865
adaptive debug: Element #2 d=669670 r=0 @t=7567441
adaptive debug: Element #3 d=672673 r=0 @t=8237111
adaptive debug: Element #4 d=561561 r=0 @t=8909784
adaptive debug: Element #5 d=654655 r=0 @t=9471345
adaptive debug: Element #6 d=630631 r=0 @t=10126000
adaptive debug: Element #7 d=666666 r=0 @t=10756631
adaptive debug: Updated MPD, next update in 7s
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR is called too late (pts_delay increased to 2168 ms)
main debug: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 1%
main debug: Buffering 2%
main debug: Received first picture
mmdevice debug: state changed: 0
main debug: Buffering 4%
...
main debug: Buffering 15%
wasapi debug: reset
main debug: Buffering 17%
...
main debug: Buffering 98%
main debug: Stream buffering done (2176 ms in 16 ms)
main debug: Decoder wait done in 0 ms
main warning: playback too early (-110003): down-sampling
mmdevice debug: state changed: 1
adaptive debug: Retrieving http://192.168.0.181:81/300/video/0/10129840.m4s @0
adaptive debug: Retrieving http://192.168.0.181:81/300/audio/5/10081200.m4s @0
adaptive debug: Retrieving http://192.168.0.181:81/300/300.mpd @0
main debug: creating access: http://192.168.0.181:81/300/300.mpd
main debug: (path: \\192.168.0.181:81\300\300.mpd)
main debug: looking for access module matching "http": 26 candidates
http debug: resolving 192.168.0.181 ...
http debug: outgoing request: GET /300/300.mpd HTTP/1.1 Host: 192.168.0.181:81 Accept: */* Accept-Language: en_US User-Agent: VLC/3.0.11 LibVLC/3.0.11 Range: bytes=0- 
http debug: incoming response: HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content Server: nginx Date: Mon, 17 Aug 2020 09:10:15 GMT Content-Type: application/octet-stream Content-Length: 10387 Last-Modified: Mon, 17 Aug 2020 09:10:15 GMT Connection: keep-alive ETag: "5f3a4977-2893" Content-Range: bytes 0-10386/10387 
main debug: using access module "access"
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_block": 24 candidates
prefetch debug: using 10387 bytes buffer, 10387 bytes read
main debug: using stream_filter module "prefetch"
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 24 candidates
main debug: no stream_filter modules matched
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "inflate": 24 candidates
main debug: no stream_filter modules matched
prefetch debug: end of stream
main debug: removing module "prefetch"
main debug: removing module "access"
main debug: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
main debug: using xml reader module "xml"
adaptive debug: MPD profile=urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011 mediaPresentationDuration=0 minBufferTime=2
adaptive debug: BaseUrl=http://192.168.0.181:81/300/
adaptive debug: Period
adaptive debug: BaseAdaptationSet 0
adaptive debug: Representation 0 [mp4a]
adaptive debug: InitSegmentTemplate #0 url=http://192.168.0.181:81/300/audio/0/audio_4.mp4 duration 0
adaptive debug: SegmentTemplate #13 url=http://192.168.0.181:81/300/audio/0/$Time$.m4s duration 0
...
```

keep getting a similar message

vlc warning and error messages when duration 5

```
adaptive debug: Timeline
adaptive debug: Element #1 d=456457 r=0 @t=9501375
adaptive debug: Element #2 d=453453 r=0 @t=9957832
adaptive debug: Element #3 d=471472 r=0 @t=10411285
adaptive debug: Element #4 d=381381 r=0 @t=10882757
adaptive debug: Element #5 d=477478 r=0 @t=11264138
adaptive debug: Element #6 d=468468 r=0 @t=11741616
adaptive debug: Element #7 d=474475 r=0 @t=12210084
adaptive debug: Element #8 d=378378 r=0 @t=12684559
adaptive debug: Element #9 d=468468 r=0 @t=13062937
adaptive debug: Element #10 d=474475 r=0 @t=13531405
adaptive debug: Updated MPD, next update in 5s
adaptive debug: Retrieving http://192.168.0.181:81/300/audio/5/8101680.m4s @0
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR is called too late (pts_delay increased to 4794 ms)
main warning: buffer too late (-588333 us): dropped
main debug: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 1%
main debug: Buffering 2%
main debug: Buffering 3%
...
main debug: Buffering 15%
main debug: Received first picture
main debug: Buffering 16%
...
main debug: Buffering 99%
main debug: Stream buffering done (4804 ms in 122 ms)
main debug: Decoder wait done in 0 ms
main debug: inserting 3246 zeroes
mmdevice debug: state changed: 0
wasapi debug: reset
main warning: playback too early (-85958): down-sampling
mmdevice debug: state changed: 1
adaptive debug: Retrieving http://192.168.0.181:81/300/video/0/8114825.m4s @0
adaptive debug: Retrieving http://192.168.0.181:81/300/300.mpd @0
main debug: creating access: http://192.168.0.181:81/300/300.mpd
main debug: (path: \\192.168.0.181:81\300\300.mpd)
main debug: looking for access module matching "http": 26 candidates
http debug: resolving 192.168.0.181 ...
http debug: outgoing request: GET /300/300.mpd HTTP/1.1 Host: 192.168.0.181:81 Accept: */* Accept-Language: en_US User-Agent: VLC/3.0.11 LibVLC/3.0.11 Range: bytes=0- 
http debug: incoming response: HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content Server: nginx Date: Mon, 17 Aug 2020 09:18:28 GMT Content-Type: application/octet-stream Content-Length: 12632 Last-Modified: Mon, 17 Aug 2020 09:18:28 GMT Connection: keep-alive ETag: "5f3a4b64-3158" Content-Range: bytes 0-12631/12632 
main debug: using access module "access"
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_block": 24 candidates
prefetch debug: using 12632 bytes buffer, 12632 bytes read
main debug: using stream_filter module "prefetch"
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 24 candidates
main debug: no stream_filter modules matched
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "inflate": 24 candidates
main debug: no stream_filter modules matched
prefetch debug: end of stream
main debug: removing module "prefetch"
main debug: removing module "access"
main debug: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
main debug: using xml reader module "xml"
adaptive debug: MPD profile=urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011 mediaPresentationDuration=0 minBufferTime=2
adaptive debug: BaseUrl=http://192.168.0.181:81/300/
adaptive debug: Period
adaptive debug: BaseAdaptationSet 0
adaptive debug: Representation 0 [mp4a]
adaptive debug: InitSegmentTemplate #0 url=http://192.168.0.181:81/300/audio/0/audio_4.mp4 duration 0
adaptive debug: SegmentTemplate #12 url=http://192.168.0.181:81/300/audio/0/$Time$.m4s duration 0
...
adaptive debug: Timeline
adaptive debug: Element #1 d=453453 r=0 @t=9957832
adaptive debug: Element #2 d=471472 r=0 @t=10411285
adaptive debug: Element #3 d=381381 r=0 @t=10882757
adaptive debug: Element #4 d=477478 r=0 @t=11264138
adaptive debug: Element #5 d=468468 r=0 @t=11741616
adaptive debug: Element #6 d=474475 r=0 @t=12210084
adaptive debug: Element #7 d=378378 r=0 @t=12684559
adaptive debug: Element #8 d=468468 r=0 @t=13062937
adaptive debug: Element #9 d=474475 r=0 @t=13531405
adaptive debug: Element #10 d=459459 r=0 @t=14005880
adaptive debug: Updated MPD, next update in 5s
adaptive debug: Retrieving http://192.168.0.181:81/300/audio/5/8550960.m4s @0
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 383 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 317 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 251 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 184 ms)
main warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 117 ms)
adaptive debug: Retrieving http://192.168.0.181:81/300/300.mpd @0
main debug: creating access: http://192.168.0.181:81/300/300.mpd
main debug: (path: \\192.168.0.181:81\300\300.mpd)
main debug: looking for access module matching "http": 26 candidates
http debug: resolving 192.168.0.181 ...
http debug: outgoing request: GET /300/300.mpd HTTP/1.1 Host: 192.168.0.181:81 Accept: */* Accept-Language: en_US User-Agent: VLC/3.0.11 LibVLC/3.0.11 Range: bytes=0- 
http debug: incoming response: HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content Server: nginx Date: Mon, 17 Aug 2020 09:18:33 GMT Content-Type: application/octet-stream Content-Length: 12596 Last-Modified: Mon, 17 Aug 2020 09:18:33 GMT Connection: keep-alive ETag: "5f3a4b69-3134" Content-Range: bytes 0-12595/12596 
main debug: using access module "access"
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_block": 24 candidates
prefetch debug: using 12596 bytes buffer, 12596 bytes read
main debug: using stream_filter module "prefetch"
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 24 candidates
main debug: no stream_filter modules matched
main debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "inflate": 24 candidates
main debug: no stream_filter modules matched
prefetch debug: end of stream
main debug: removing module "prefetch"
main debug: removing module "access"
main debug: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
main debug: using xml reader module "xml"
adaptive debug: MPD profile=urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011 mediaPresentationDuration=0 minBufferTime=2
adaptive debug: BaseUrl=http://192.168.0.181:81/300/
adaptive debug: Period
adaptive debug: BaseAdaptationSet 0
adaptive debug: Representation 0 [mp4a]
adaptive debug: InitSegmentTemplate #0 url=http://192.168.0.181:81/300/audio/0/audio_4.mp4 duration 0
adaptive debug: SegmentTemplate #13 url=http://192.168.0.181:81/300/audio/0/$Time$.m4s duration 0
...
```

keep getting a similar message

This is played on vlc. this is duration 10 sec. but I want to live streaming duration 5 under.
cuda, framerate, GOP size and bitrate are fixed.

I know that is inefficient. but now, I have to live stream channel multiview duration 5 under. How can I achieve? please help me.